# Strip string after third occurrence of character python

Tags: python

I want to strip all characters after a third character, say - for instance.

I found this code online and it works but I'm having trouble learning how it works and wanted to ask so I can understand it fully.

```
 def indexList(s, item, i=0):
    """
    Return an index list of all occurrances of 'item' in string/list 's'.
    Optional start search position 'i'
    """
    i_list = []
    while True:
        try:
            i = s.index(item, i)
            i_list.append(i)
            i += 1
        except:
            break
    return i_list

def strip_chrs(s, subs):
    for i in range(indexList(s, subs)[-1], len(s)):
        if s[i+1].isalpha():
            return data[:i+1]

data = '115Z2113-3-777-55789ABC7777'
print strip_chrs(data, '-')
```

Here's my questions
on the while True: line what's true?
Also on the except: Except what? and why does is a break coded there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you tag this Python 3.x? You use Python 2.x syntax in your `print` statement.

Comment: are you trying to strip all characters after the third occurence of another? So in your `data` example are you trying to strip out everything after `115Z2113-3-777` ?

Comment: Yes, 55789ABC7777 should be stripped. I tagged Python 3.x because I'm currently learning it. I'll remove the tag though my apologies

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
def trunc_at(s, d, n=3):
    "Returns s truncated at the n'th (3rd by default) occurrence of the delimiter, d."
    return d.join(s.split(d, n)[:n])

print trunc_at("115Z2113-3-777-55789ABC7777", "-")
```

How it works:

1. The string `s` is split into a list at each occurrence of the delimiter `d` using `s.split(d)`. We use the second argument to `split` to indicate the maximum number of splits to do (since there's no reason to keep splitting after the first `n` times). The result is a list, such as `["115Z2113", "3", "777", "55789ABC7777"]`
2. A slice of the first `n` items of the list is taken using `[:n]`. The result is another list, such as `["115Z2113", "3", "777"]`
3. The list is joined back into a string, placing the delimiter `d` between each item of the list,using `d.join(...)`, resulting in, for example, `"115Z2113-3-777"`

Comment: Me likee.

Stupid length limits.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of it, and +1 for not using itertools :)

Comment: Here i am in 2022 getting the simpler code samples!! thanks for this one liner!

Answer (score 11):

In a one-liner way :

```
data = '115Z2113-3-777-55789ABC7777'
strip_character = "-"
>>> strip_character.join(data.split(strip_character)[:3])
'115Z2113-3-777'
```

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
 while True:
```

creates an infinite loop. It's just going to keep looping there until either the program crashes or a `break` is called. The `except` line is an exception handler that is going to catch any exceptions, at which point `break` is called exiting the infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

On the "while True", True is simply the constant value True.  So while True is loop-forever or until broken.

the except is using the exception that happens when s.index  finds no more string after i as a way to break the loop.  This is a Bad Thing.

try something like this (pseudocode):

```
while you still have string left:
   get index of next '-'
   if found, add 1 to count
   if count == 3:
      return s[index+1:]
```

the `s[index+1:]` returns the substring from the character following index, to the end.